# Converting x number of petaFLOPS into a base 2 number

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I would like a few different formulas or methods for doing a couple of conversions and calculations:

1) How can I convert [petaFLOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PetaFLOPS) into a base $2$ number representing how many operations per second e.g. $2^{64}$? For example, if we assume a computer capable of $27$ petaFLOPS, how many operations per second can it perform in the format of $2^x$? I would like to be able to plug in different values into the formula to change the number of petaFLOPS e.g. $200, 1000$ and get different outputs.

2) If I get a result from the above formula, e.g. $2^{85}$ operations per second, I need a second formula to determine how long it would take in seconds to do $2^x$ operations e.g. $2^{100}$ operations.

My mathematical symbol understanding is not too good, so if you could write out the answer in simple, plain English without strange mathematical symbols and so on that would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: So, what definitions are you using.... one petaFLOPS is $10^{15}$ FLOPS?  or $2^{50}$ FLOPS?  (similar to the question of whether a kilobyte is $1000$ byes or $1024$ bytes.)

Comment: @GEdgar, I'm not sure, try the [info on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PetaFLOPS), I think the definition is 10^15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 petaFlop = $10^{15} \frac{\text{flop}}{\text{s}}$ and we want to find $n$ such that $2^n=k\cdot10^{15}$ where $k$ is the number of petaFlops

Take log base 2 of both sides:

$$\log_{2}{2^n}=n$$

$$\log_{2}{(k\cdot10^{15})}$$

So we know $n=\log_2{(k\cdot10^{15})}$

So 1 petaFlop is about $2^{49.82892}$ operations per second. But in general, $k$ petaFLOP is the same as $2^{\log_2{(k\cdot10^{15})}}$ FLOP.

Now, if you are running at $2^a$ operations per second and need to do $2^b$ operations, it will take

$$\frac{2^b \text{flop}}{2^a \frac{\text{flop}}{\text{s}}}=2^{b-a} \text{s}$$

Hope this helps. :)

---

In as non-math language as possible:

$$k\; \text{petaFLOP} = 2^{\log_2{(k\cdot10^{15})}} \;\text{FLOP}$$

And if you are running at $2^k \text{FLOP}$ and need to perform $2^x$ actions, it will take

$$2^{x-k}\; \text{s}$$

Comment: That squiggly = symbol, does that loosely translate to 'becomes'?

Comment: @user162543 That $\approx$ symbol is read as "is approximately equal to" in the same way that $=$ is read as "is equal to". For example, $3.9999999\approx4$ is read as $3.9999999$ is approximately equal to $4$. Also, I made a change to make the computation easier.

Comment: Alright awesome, thanks very much. Let's just check my workings are right using your formula. So a 27 petaFLOP computer would be capable of 2^54.58 operations per second. Then to do 2^80 operations it will take 2^25.42 seconds, which is 44775074 seconds ≈ 1.4 years. Sound about right?

Comment: @user162543 Correct!

Comment: Alright, excellent. Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note also that $k\; \text{petaFLOP} = 2^{\log_2{(k\cdot10^{15})}} \;\text{FLOP} \approx 2^{49.8289\ldots + \log_2 k} \;\text{FLOP}$ because $\log_2{(k\cdot10^{15})} = \log_2 10^{15} + \log_2 k = 49.8289\ldots + \log_2 k$. This about 49.8 would be 50 if we assumed that one petaFLOPS is $2^{50}$ FLOPS.